# Font awesome error - "blocked by CORS policy"

Tags: magento2.3, cors

While loading my website, at some times `icons` are not displaying.

```
"blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."
```

[image: Error]

Comment: are you on localhost ?

Comment: No, in my live server

Comment: This issue is occurring because you are invoking the content from the different site & the other thing is that the other site is not `https://`

Answer (score -1):

Please Can you open your .htaccess file  and put below Code in .htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|woff2|font.css|css|js)$">
      Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

it allows you to access all resources and webfonts from all domains.
Hope this is helpful.